# How to organize a large number of Routes in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-studio

We have a lot of routes for our application.  We are using **child_routes** to try to keep them organized, but the config files still get very long and difficult to read through.

Does anyone know of a better way to organize the routes?

We're using Zend Studio, does anyone know of tools in it that can help?

Answer (score 3):

**TL\DR: not using ZF2**

Well, that's config files and the current routing and there's nothing really to change that. When it comes to ZF3 however, the routing config should go down a little. This becomes even more true when you'll be using the short array syntax `[]`.

You can take a loot at the draft of the ZF3 Router [here](https://github.com/GeeH/Dash#child-routes) (remember, this can still change!)

Using indexed parameters for routes, we'll be able to keep the config to a minimum of what we need. And considering you'll be using php 5.5 it can be simplified even further using `UserController::class` instead of `Application\Controller\UserController`

Comment: Up vote for hope! Also, didn't think about using the new 5.5 features. We're in a closed production so we can use them now, thanks.